# Problemas con vsftp y /var/www/html

Tags: ftp, centos7

Tengo el siguiente problema que no puedo resolver, no se como configurar vsftp para acceder al directorio /var/www/html para subir archivos desde un cliente ftp, por ejemplo FileZilla.

- Instale CentOS 7 en una maquina virtual.
- Luego instale httpd.
- Luego instale MySQL (MariaDB).
- Luego instale PHP.
- Hasta ahí todo bien, desde el navegador con la ip puedo acceder al index.php que esta en /var/www/html.

Ahora ese index.php fue editado dentro del servidor con el editor nano, lo que quiero hacer es editar los archivos desde mi sistema anfitrion (Windows) y subirlos a /var/www/html desde FileZilla.

He seguido muchas guias pero ninguna me ha funcionado. Agradecería si alguien me puede ayudar, gracias.

Comment: Finalmente encontre una solucion a mi problema dejo el link si alguno tiene la misma necesidad que yo tenia:
http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/other-linux-distributions/194663-ftp-user-var-www-html.html

En el cliente Ftp hay que usar el protocolo SFTP.

Comment: Editar el archivo /etc/passwd
 webguy:x:1001:1001::/var/www/html:/bin/bash